# Configure Apache Solr 6.5.0 into Magento 2.1.3 Community Edition

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, solr, apache2

How to configure Apache Solr 6.5.0 into Magento-2.1.3 Community Edition.

I have followed this [official Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/solr/solr-magento.html) but it is only for Magento EE.

Please provide some documentation or steps where I can start implementation Solr Search to Magento 2 CE.

Comment: Having issues getting this to work with magento 1.9. When i try to test connection it keeps saying `unknown solr and java version`

Comment: Check this post from inchoo, it looks quite easy. http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-add-solr-elasticsearch/